# How to compile shader by code in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I wrote some shader code in unity editor:  Assets > Create > Shader > Standard Surface Shader then after created I did double click on it and visual studio 2022 opened with the shader code.

I added my own code too but now how to compile it ?  there is no build in the visual studio menu. for some reason when opened the shader in visual studio the menu is different.

[image: visual studio menu when opening a shader file]

Comment: it should be compiled when you click back to unity, like everything else